# AppCompat looking ugly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity, visual-glitch

I'm having a strange "glitch" in some parts of my apps when using Appcompatthemes (Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) and Appcompatactivities.My project's using appcompat-v7:27.0.2 and design:27.0.2 .

When opening spinners once, everything is normal. As soon as you open the spinner a second time, the layout breaks.
When trying to copy/paste/cut something from an EditText layout the selection bar breaks.

See screenshots(gifs):

[image: here1]
[image: here2]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found out, that it had to do something with my style.

The solution is to set`<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` to false. Then the glitch was fixed. I still think it's a bug inside of Appcompat, but for now that's my workaround.